# custom begining keyframe of CAAnimation / changing animation speed during animation

Tags: ios, scenekit

Is it possible to set custom begining keyframe of animation from collada, .dae file?
For example to make an animation a half-length of animation.
Or is it possible to change animation speed during that animation?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the timing of an animation so that you start at an arbitrary time, it is also possible to change the speed of an animation (before it is added to the node).

Look at the `timeOffset` and `speed` properties in the CAMediaTiming protocol (which CAAnimation confirms to)

I've [previously written](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/) about how use these and the other timing properties to control the timing of an animation.